# Nested Dictionary Call

Tags: ios, swift

I am having an issue trying to do a nested dictionary call. Currently the error is

> Value of type '[AnyHashable : Any]?' has no member 'value'.

For my code I have:

```
private var objBusinessDetails: BusinessDetailsObject?
let root_dict = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(
    with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [AnyHashable: Any]
```

And my dictionary call is:

```
objBusinessDetails?.strFavouriteCount = 
    root_dict?.value(forKey: "businessdetails")?.value(forKey: "favouriteCount")
```

I have also tried, but this doesn't work either:

```
objBusinessDetails?.strFavouriteCount = 
    root_dict?["businessdetails"]?["favouriteCount"]++
```

I have to do this multiple times, for example:

```
objBusinessDetails?.strFavouriteCount = root_dict?.value(forKey: "businessdetails")?.value(forKey: "favouriteCount")
                    objBusinessDetails?.strisOpen = root_dict?.value(forKey: "businessdetails")?.value(forKey: "isOpen")
                    objBusinessDetails?.strCoverPrice = root_dict?.value(forKey: "businessdetails")?.value(forKey: "coverPrice")
                    objBusinessDetails?.strMyFavStatus = root_dict?.value(forKey: "businessdetails")?.value(forKey: "addtofavourites")
                    objBusinessDetails?.strFilterDetails = root_dict?.value(forKey: "businessdetails")?.value(forKey: "drink_type")
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do this. Sorry for my noobiness, just began programming in swift. Thanks in advance!

Best,

Tony

Answer (score 0):

The function `value(forKey:)` is a KVC (Key Value Coding) function. It only works on Objective-C objects, and you should not use it except in very specific circumstances. For a newb, don't use it at all. (When you get to the point where you say "Oh, this API uses KVC, so I need to use `value(forKey:)` here", you're ready to use it. Until that point, pretend it doesn't exist.)

The JSONSerialization class returns data of type `Any`. If you cast it to type `[AnyHashable:Any]` (a generic dictionary) then the value you get back for a given key will not be the desired type, another dictionary. You need to cast your result to a dictionary containing a dictionary.

Considering the following example code:

```
//`aThing` simulates the result of calling JSONSerialization
var aThing: Any = ["key":["innerKey": "savedValue"]]

//Try to cast `aThing to a dictionary containing another dictionary with a `String` key.
guard let nestedDict = aThing as? [String: [String:Any]]
  else {
    //In real code, your guard would be in a function and you'd use `else { return nil }` rather than `fatalError()`
    fatalError("Invalid dictinary")
}

if let value = nestedDict["key"]?["innerKey"] {
  print("Found value \"\(value)\"")
} else {
  print("Failed to find nested keys '[\"key\"][\"innerKey\"]' in dictionary")
}
```

### EDIT:

Note that the above is much improved with the new `JSONDecoder` class in Swift 4. You can use that to encode/decode known types to/from JSON.